# Estimate RAM usage information of an embedded device

Tags: embedded, linux, ram, arm9

I'm monitoring the performance of an ARM-based embedded device which runs poky linux distro (from Yocto project) which contains OpenEmbedded build system. I need to get the MHz (CPU cycles) consumption and the RAM used for any process that runs on the system. Though `top` utility allows me to see the CPU % used (which allows me to estimate CPU MHz in turn), it just gives the *virtual memory size (VSZ)* used by the process but no *physical memory* used.

Is there a way I can get this information I need?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a general Linux question not anything specifically related to embedded systems.

Comment: @PeterJ general-purpose Linux distributions have a usable version of `top` able to display physical memory usage. This issue is specific to Yocto/OpenEmbedded.

Comment: @PeterJ : Yeah. This is a bit ambiguous regarding classification of what it comes under. But I believe it is as much related to embedded systems as much as to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` command on Linux readily reports you virtual memory used by the process (the VIRT column), physical RAM used by the process exclusively (the RES column) as well as its shared memory (the SHR column). You probably want the RES column.

If your version of `top` doesn't have these columns, consider building a decent version from sources, or use [`htop`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/htop) or [`pmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html), whichever is available.

Comment: Yes. my version of `top` is the culprit I guess. I understand that is a solution. I was wondering if I have any alternate way. Like some utility which I was unaware of. Do we have such a solution?

Comment: Have you checked for `htop` or `pmap`?

Comment: Yup. Both are not available in this distro. :(

Comment: When I used Yocto, I added htop to an image I was building. Take a look how to add it to the build proccess.

Comment: @ricardomenzer : Sure. Will do.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev : So, this is the only way I can achieve my objective?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit No, there are potentially countless ways to extract  information from `/proc/$pid/maps`. You can even parse that information yourself with a script.

Comment: Appreciate the hint. Will consider both your suggestions (though parsing from /proc/$pid/maps would be a bit more tedious).